# How to Sync two AWS Buckets using ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I have some objects in Bucket A which needs to be synced up with Bucket B.
In AWS CLI, I used to do something like this below

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a/folder s3://bucket-b/folder
```

Is there any similar command in ansible to sync buckets rather than copying them individually? I'm new to ansible and I couldnt find much information on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If any time you need to execute a specific command that is not included in ansible modules, you can use the aws-cli command directly with [Ansible's Shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html).

eg:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1 
  connection: local

  tasks: 
  - name: Describe Load Balancers 
    register: logs 
    local_action: 
      module: shell aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a/folder s3://bucket-b/folder

  - name: Print LOGs 
    debug: var=logs
```